# help with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed Ruby.
When I start the Mongreal server I get this error message

```
the program cant start because msvcrt-ruby18.dll is missing
```

I even downloaded the file msvcrt-ruby18.dll, but no use

I googled it, but cannot solve the problem

Comment: What version of ruby did you install?

Comment: ruby 1.9.1p429 (2010-07-02 revision 28523) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: I don't think Mongrel and Ruby 1.9.x play well together (at least the last time I looked). I would suggest using Thin (http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) instead of Mongrel. Or fall back to Ruby 1.8 which is hardly satisfactory

Comment: do i hv to uninstall mongreal to install thin?

Comment: i got this error wen installing thin


ERROR:  Error installing thin:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago. What I did was installing Ruby 1.8.6 (using the installer for windows) and copying all the dll's from the 'bin' folder that did not exist at the 1.9 ruby's bin.